# if==True;but built-in functions doesn't run

Tags: arrays, r, string, function

```
f <- readLines('/home/dogus/Desktop/phonezzzz/vcards.txt', encoding="UTF-8")

#empty lists
names <- c()
numbers <- c()

phonezz <- function(){

  for(i in 1:length(f)){

    if("FN" == substring(f[i],0,2)){
    name <- substring(f[i],4)  # doesn't run
    number <- substring(f[i+1],10) # doesn't run

    names <- c(names, name) # doesn't run ; append 'name' into the 'names' list
    numbers <- c(numbers, number) # doesn't run
    print("Hello World")}

    else{
    print("------") 
    next
      }
  }
}
phonezz()
names
```

Here is the gist link: https://gist.github.com/dgsbicak/b9e2d4fb1dbb70c964295ef88120f404

I use R Studio.

When I run this script, in Global Environment section it shows:

Values:

```
f           chr[1:3000] "some string" "some string2" "FN:213123123123" ...
names       NULL (empty)
numbers     NULL (empty)
```

Functions:

```
phonezz     function ()
```

So name and number variables are not even exists; names list shows an empty list.
And as I said it returns lots of "Hello World".
So I dont understand what is the problem?

Kind Regards,

EDIT:

```
f <- readLines('/home/dogus/Desktop/phonezzzz/vcards.txt', encoding="UTF-8")

names <- c()
numbers <- c()

phonezz <- function() {for(i in 1:length(f))
  {
    if("FN" == substring(f[i],0,2)){
      name <<- substring(f[i],4)
      number <<- substring(f[i+1],10)
      names <<- c(names, name)
      numbers <<- c(numbers, number)
      print("Hello World")
      return(list(names, numbers))
    }
    else{
      print("------")
      next
    }
  }
}
phone <- phonezz()
phone
```

Now the result is:

Values:

```
f         chr[1:3089] "asdasd" "asdasd" ...
name      "just last person's name"
number    "just last person's number"

names     "just last person's name in the list"
numbers   "just last person's number in the list"
phone     List of 2
```

Functions:

```
phonezz   function ()
```

Comment: You  need to add `return(list(names, numbers))` to the end of your function

Comment: You could use `<<-` when assigning to names and numbers to go out of the environment of the function, but @CPak idea is better because your function doesn't change the world outside of its scope

Comment: Same thing happens.I changed <- with <<- also put return(list(names, numbers)) at the end of if. Still same results.

Comment: There is also a **logical bug**. If you loop from `1` to `length(f)` then what is `f[i + 1]` when at the last iteration of the loop, when `i = length(f)`? Also, I would put `names <- c()` and `numbers <- c()` as the first two lines of the function, i.e., inside the function.

Comment: The for lop is probably running. You could put a print statement in there to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `names` and `numbers` do not exist outside of the function `phonezz()` 
Add the `return(list(names, numbers)` as suggested above. 
Then call the function as `test_list <- phonezz()`. The variable `test_list` should contain the names and numbers.

Comment: I've updated the original post.It seems new person names/numbers can't be appended into names/numbers lists.

Comment: Just wrong. Failure to understand the scope of the `for` function, and well as how to initialize a list.

Answer (score 1):

This does not create a list:

```
numbers <- c()
```

Proof:

```
is.list(c())
[1] FALSE
```

Use instead:

```
my.names <- list()   #don't use `names` ... it's the name of a function
numbers <- list()
```

Then another problem is that a `for`-loop does not return anything (except, it does return NULL, but that's rarely useful). It only operates in the local environment of your function. A further (minor) problem is that indexing in R starts at 1 (NOT 0) so `substring(f[i],0,2)` probably doesn't really make sense. If you had commented your code, we might know if you wanted 2 or 3 letters. I'm guessing 2, since you compare to "FN". Use `substring(f[i],1,2)`. And then look at:

```
 substring("string", 4)
[1] "ing"  # so it returns the entire "tail" of the the input character value
```

Then there is a further problem that your `for`-loop is overwriting EVERY value. So you should not be surprised if you only get one set of values. You need to index items inside the `for`-loop and then OUTSIDE the loop you need to additionally apply the `return` operation. The `<<-` is only going to push those values one level "up" which is still inside the function environment. Nothing is going to happen outside.

If you had a complete example we could deliver a worked solution but I think this should help you understand the several problems that are immediately visible in your effort to start learning R. See [MCVE] and "how to make a great reproducible example in R"